# Custom success message on FilePond file upload

Tags: filepond

I’m using FilePond 4.30.4 with React and react-filepond 7.1.2.  Everything is working great and I can upload files.

My server responds with a file ID, and this comes back down to FilePond.  I can see it in the onprocessfile event.

I’d like to include this is the ‘Upload Complete’ message.  e.g. ‘Complete, file 12345’.   How can I set this?

I’ve tried to update .labelFileProcessingComplete in onprocessfile, but it has no effect.  I can see my events being fired and the correct data in the console.  Perhaps there is another way to update the 'Upload Complete' label with a custom message for the file.

```js
<FilePond
          ref={filePondRef}
          oninit={() => handleInit()}
          files={files}
          onupdatefiles={setFiles}
          onprocessfile={ (error, file) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('OnProcessFile: we have an error:' + error);
                    console.dir(error);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('OnProcessFile:File processed', file);
                console.log('OnProcessFile:set processed message to ', file.serverId);
        //This has no effect
                filePondRef.current.labelFileProcessingComplete='Completed:-#' + file.serverId;
            }
          }
          labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
          server={ {
            timeout: 7000,
            process: {
              url: apiUrl,
              method: 'POST',
              withCredentials: false,
              timeout: 7000,
              onload: (res) => {
                console.log('onload:and label with res=' + res);
        // this has no effect either
                filePondRef.current.labelFileProcessingComplete='Completed:' + res;
                return res;
              }
          }
        }
        }
        labelFileProcessingError= {() => {
          // replaces the error on the FilePond error label
          console.log('labelFileProcessingError: serverResponse is:' + serverResponse );
          return serverResponse;
        }}
        />
```